# Tfs database restore in QA instance

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-migration

Here is the setup I have.... a tfs production server tfs 2015 and a QA server tfs 2015. No one uses QA instance of tfs and the database had not been updated for 6 months.

I would like to update the QA tfs database to production database. When I try restore database, ending up with errors on database conflicts.

How to maintain a replica of production database in QA tfs instance?.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How did you backup the production databases?

Comment: Using tfs schedule backups... thanks

Comment: Then you have to restore the Tfs_Configuration + TFS_<Collection> databases. At which step do you have errors? During the SQL Server restore process?

Comment: It keeps on going for ever while checking on conflicting database check when verifying the restore.

Comment: Do you mean you have two TFS and you want to combine them? What's in the QA tfs, are there only work items?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, I have a production TFS instance and a QA TFS Instance(for testing TFS changes before moving them to Production). But the database of QA Instance is not upto date. and would like to match the QA database to that of production database. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset your TFS instance before you can setup the new one. To do that first call "tfconfig setup /uninstall:all".

This will reset your TFS to its unconfigured state. Then you need to delete all of the databases; config, collections, reporting, cube.

Then initiate the restore using the "Restore" option on the start menu.

**Make sure that you run "tfconfig changeserverid" before you reconfigure TFS on the new restore or you will have conflicts with production**

Comment: Nope, SQL server does not work that way. And you have to reconfigure your TFS instance to use the new database.

Comment: Thank you @mrhinsh

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful link [Setup a test TFS with production datslabases](https://roadtoalm.com/2016/01/28/set-up-a-test-tfs-environment-with-production-databases/)
You need to make sure the backup files are compatible with the version of SQL server on the QA

Comment: Thanks, @mahmoud. I will try to implement the steps and update you.